# How to properly tween mesh using quaternions?

Tags: three.js

I have cobbled together a tween function (*with enormous help from SO*) to tween a mesh...and it's working fine.

My question is that - I feel that the way I am doing it is inefficient and I'm am looking for a better solution.

For example I am cloning my mesh each time I call the function...and that is so I can call rotateOnAxis().  I know what I want is a target quaternion that is my mesh rotation incremented on the axis...but I just haven't been able to find a better way to get it.

As usual any help much appreciated.

PS. really loving threejs!!!

```
function tweenRot(obj, axis, angle){
        var actp = obj.clone(); // seems wasteful
        actp.rotateOnAxis( axis, angle );
        var targq = actp.quaternion;

        var qm = new THREE.Quaternion(); 
        var curQuaternion = obj.quaternion;

        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({t:0}).to({t:1}, 500)
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut )
            .onUpdate(function(){
                THREE.Quaternion.slerp(curQuaternion, targq, qm, this.t);
                qm.normalize();
                obj.rotation.setFromQuaternion(qm)
            });

        tween.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to tween an object's rotation by specifying an `axis` of rotation and an `angle`. You can to that like so:

```
var tweenRotateOnAxis = function() {

    // axis is assumed to be normalized
    // angle is in radians

    var qStart = new THREE.Quaternion();
    var o = new THREE.Object3D();

    return function tweenRotateOnAxis( object, axis, angle ) {

        var qEnd, time = { t: 0 };

        // start quaternion
        qStart.copy( object.quaternion );

        // end quaternion
        o.quaternion.copy( qStart );
        o.rotateOnAxis( axis, angle );
        qEnd = o.quaternion;

        // tween
        new TWEEN.Tween( time )
            .to( { t : 1 }, 1000 )
            .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Linear.EaseNone )
            .onUpdate( function() {
                THREE.Quaternion.slerp( qStart, qEnd, object.quaternion, time.t );
            } )
            .onComplete( function() {
                object.quaternion.copy( qEnd ); // to be exact
            } )
            .start();

    };

}();
```

This should be reasonably efficient, even if you call it repeatedly. The rotation will be in object space.

Don't forget to call `TWEEN.update()` in your render loop.

three.js r.75